# how to align equations with some text

Tags: equations, align, text-decorations

I want to align the equations with text. Though the equations are aligned as I want it to be but still the text is not aligned.

```
\begin{align}
 \mathscr{F}^\prime(x_0)^{-1}&\in L(Y,X) \quad &\textrm{for some } x_0\in{D}; \nonumber\\
\big\Vert{\mathscr{F}^\prime(x_0)^{-1}\mathscr{F}(x_0)}\big\Vert&\le {\color{red}\eta} &{}\nonumber
\\
\big\Vert{\mathscr{F}^\prime(x_0)^{-1}\big[\mathscr{F}^\prime(x)-\mathscr{F}^\prime(x_0)\big]}
\big\Vert &\le L_0
\left\Vert{x-x_0}\right\Vert\quad &\textrm{for all } x\in{D}; \nonumber\\
\big\Vert{\mathscr{F}^\prime(x_0)^{-1}\big[\mathscr{F}^\prime(x)-\mathscr{F}^\prime(y)\big]}
\big\Vert &\le L
\left\Vert{x-y}\right\Vert\quad &\textrm{for all } x,y\in{D}; \nonumber\\
h_{AH} = \xoverline{L}_{\eta} &\le \dfrac{1}{2} &{}
\intertext{and}
\xoverline{U}(x_0,\lambda_0) &\subseteq D, &{}\nonumber
\end{align}
```

Another question: is there any way to write the preceding equations more aesthetically? Thank your response.

Comment: Please add 4 more lines needed (`\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`)to make it compilable MWE so that our wizards can directly copy/paste your code and start work on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put the text in the fourth column, which is left aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,xcolor,mathtools}

\let\xoverline\overline % supply your definition

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}'(x_0)^{-1} 
  &\in L(Y,X)
  && \text{for some } x_0\in{D}; 
  \nonumber\\
\lVert\mathscr{F}'(x_0)^{-1}\mathscr{F}(x_0)\rVert 
  &\le \textcolor{red}{\eta} 
  \nonumber\\
\lVert\mathscr{F}'(x_0)^{-1}[\mathscr{F}'(x)-\mathscr{F}'(x_0)]\rVert 
  &\le L_0\lVert x-x_0\rVert 
  && \text{for all } x\in{D}; 
  \nonumber\\
\lVert\mathscr{F}'(x_0)^{-1}[\mathscr{F}'(x)-\mathscr{F}'(y)]\rVert 
  &\le L\lVert x-y\rVert 
  &&\text{for all } x,y\in{D}; 
  \nonumber\\
h_{AH} = \xoverline{L}_{\eta} 
  &\le \dfrac{1}{2}
\shortintertext{and}
\xoverline{U}(x_0,\lambda_0) 
  &\subseteq D, 
  \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I've removed all the `\big` commands (which should be `\bigl` and `\bigr` for left and right delimiters, but don't seem necessary here). Instead I used `\lVert` and `\rVert` to state precisely the nature of the symbols, whether opening or closing delimiters. The shorthand `'` is equivalent to `^{\prime}`. Finally, `\shortintertext` from the `mathtools` package requires less vertical space than `\intertext`.

It's not clear what the number refers to, the whole alignment or just the central equation.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\dfrac` for the last `1/2` fraction, doesn't `\tfrac` look better?

Comment: @daleif Possibly, but I like a big fraction better, in alignments; in this case `\tfrac` may be good for keeping the rythm of the lines. I didn't change that from the original input.

Comment: I usually recommend using `\tfrac` is the fraction is *simple* and is the only thing tall on the line

Comment: @egreg: I'm sorry to pester you like this, but I remember once asking you, in a comment, about the difference between `\bigl/\bigr` and just `\big`, i.e., when to use the one or the other, but I cannot for the life of me now find that answer you gave (I've searched my own profile's "responses"-tab as well as your username with query `\left \bigl`). Since this answer touches on the topic as well, could I ask for a reiteration? TIA! `:-)`

Comment: `\big` produces an ordinary symbol, `\bigl` an opening symbol and `\bigr)` a closing one. This is relevant for spacing: try `\log\big(` and `\log\bigl(` to see the difference.